# Android Studio database inspector not working with Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1 and the new "database inspector" component is critical for my work. It works correctly with Android Studio's emulator but not with Genymotion and does not show anything.

I'm using the latest version of Genymotion(3.1.2) on Windows10 and all device images have API level +26 ( which is required for database inspector)

I couldn't find any useful information on the component help page[image]

Is there any way to use "database inspector" with Genymotion?

Comment: Same issue, works with AVD but not Genymotion

Answer (score 1):

my androidStudio version is 2022.1.1 and Genymotion is Version 3.3.2 and problem persist
work with avd and not work with Genymotion